# Should I use finalizers to unlock or release any thread locks or other resources?

Tags: java, multithreading

following is written in Effective Java 2nd addition : -

For example, depending on a finalizer to release a persistent lock on a shared resource
such as a database is a good way to bring your entire distributed system to a
grinding halt.

Because,

It is entirely possible, even likely, that a program terminates without executing
finalizers on some objects that are no longer reachable.

Then is it ok to write following code?

```
 public void doSomething(long abc) {
    //Needs to wait on lock to avoid updates
    ReentrantLock lock = mainLock;
    lock.lock();

    try {

    } finally {
        if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case, unlocking is necessary because you are getting a reference to, probably, a static ReentrantLock of your class, so in your example you need the finally block, for sure.

Comment: `finally` does not equal `finalize()` (The latter is a method that may or may not be called when an Object gets garbage collected)

Comment: Got your point @Neel, was doing a silly mistake of thinking finalizer as finally. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking finalizers (implementations of the [Object.finalize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) method) for `finally` blocks.

If you override the `finalize()` method, you cannot trust it will always be called before the garbage collector destroys the object.

A `finally` block is more reliable; it is always executed even if an exception is thrown inside the corresponding `try` block and thus it is safe to free up resources inside of it.

Comment: More often than you'd think. See http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec7

Answer (score 0):

You must always unlock Locks in finally{} block. You shouldn't do the `lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()` check, since lock is always acquired by the current thread if program reaches the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the below code

```
lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()
```

just do it:

```
finally {     
            lock.unlock();        
    }
```